# picklist value not recognized in the test

Tags: apex, failing-tests

When trying the test class for the related picklist value in a Quote field i get the following message:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, bad value for restricted picklist field: 3668: [Sales_Org__c]

But the value 3668 exists and it's free of errors in the org. Any idea? thanks

Comment: Are you using record types for Quotes?

Answer (score 2):

This is a recently introduced feature which makes sure that we don't accidentally enter wrong value in pick-list which actually doesn't exist.
There are only two ways you can get this error:-

1. You are trying to enter non-existing value to that pick-list field and restricted pick-list is enabled.
2. Object contains record types and that particular value is not available for that Record type. Restricted Pick-list feature is enabled.

Comment: Can you please add a link to documentation.  I have started to run into this problem.